# Jquery UI progressbar not animating with asp button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, progress-bar

I'm trying to use a jQuery UI progressbar that would show in a jQuery UI dialog when I click on an `asp:Button`.

The Button is declared as follow :

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Télécharger" 
    CausesValidation="False" onclick="Button2_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:displayDialog()"/>
```

The dialog is declared as follow :

```
<div id="dialog" title="Attente de téléchargement">
<p>Le fichier est en cours de préparation, le téléchargement devrait commencer sous peu.</p>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
</div>
```

And eventually the javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialog").hide();
    });

    function displayDialog() {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: false
        });
        $("#dialog").show();
    }
</script>
```

This seems to work fine (since Both onclick and OnClientclick function are called). The code behind is executed correctly and the dialog shows too. However the animation of the progress bar doesnt work (see image below).

[image]

I don't understand what's going on. I've tried to not use show/hide but the property `.css("display","none")` and `.css("display","block")` of the `$("#dialog")` and the result is the same.

However If I don't hide the dialog on the `$(document).ready` the animation works fine. When I run this in  the script tag:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: false
        });
    });
```

The dialog shows directly at the loading of the page like this :

[image]

which is correct (I obviously don't want it at the start but when you click on the button but still the progressbar shows correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You are finding this issue because you have enclosed your `progress bar` within the `dialog div`

**ERROR CODE:**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Attente de téléchargement">
  <p>Le fichier est en cours de préparation, le téléchargement devrait commencer sous peu.</p>
  <div id="progressbar"></div>
</div>
```

Applying any changes to the Hidden elements would reflect.so better thing to do is to move the progress bar outside the `dialog` div.

**CORRECTED CODE:**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Attente de téléchargement">
   <p>Le fichier est en cours de préparation, le téléchargement devrait commencer sous peu.</p>
</div>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: That won't work since I need the progressbar within the dialog. Furthemore I tried first to use only a progress bar and show hide it (without any dialog) and the result was the same.

Comment: @WizLiz: could you create a jsfiddle, so that i can check on it.http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @WizLiz: i have created jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/DU63h/5/ . i can see that u havent given  any value for the progress bar for it to show loading .

Comment: Yes, I know, I'm using value: false so it show like http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#indeterminate

Comment: @WizLiz: i can see that , there were some issues wit the jquery ui  lib your using, no prob with your code. check here ,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/DU63h/16/

Comment: How did you achieve that ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47672/discussion-between-dreamweiver-and-wizliz)